# TypeError: routes.map is not a function ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, routes

What I'm trying to do is create the route scheme for my reactjs application. However when I start my application and the routes are loaded it displays this error.

Error:

[image]

Error file:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
// reactstrap components
import { Container, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";

// core components
import AuthNavbar from "components/Navbars/AuthNavbar.js";
import AuthFooter from "components/Footers/AuthFooter.js";

import routes from "routes.js";

class Auth extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.classList.add("bg-default");
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.classList.remove("bg-default");
  }
  getRoutes = routes => {
    return routes.map((prop, key) => {
      if (prop.layout === "/auth") {
        return (
          <Route
            path={prop.layout + prop.path}
            component={prop.component}
            key={key}
          />
        );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  };
```

My routes file(routes.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.js";
import AuthLayout from "layouts/Auth.js";

export default function Routes() {
  return(
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={AuthLayout}/>
      <Route path="/admin" exact component={AdminLayout}/>
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that? Can't you use your routes.js as a component?

Comment: I don't know much about reactjs. I got the dashboard template from that site and I'm trying to implement the routes to do the authentication. As I understand it this dashboard comes with a different route scheme that does not use route.js. If you want to see the template with the code I downloaded, here is the link: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/argon-dashboard

I will be very grateful if you can help me.